# How to sum the values of a vector based on monotonicity of other vector (increased/decreased)

Tags: r

I have this dataset

```
x<-c(52,52,51,51,51,51,50,50,50,49,49,49,49,48,48,50,60,70,80,90,100,100,100,100,100,100,99,98,98,95,94,80,70,60,70,80,90,100,100,100,90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20,10,70,90,10)
y<-c(rep(c(30),times(51)))
y<-c(NA,y)
x
y
data<-cbind(x,y)
data<-data.frame(data)
data
```

All I want is to sum the y variable when x is increased when decreased and vice versa

Well I tried this

```
d <- c(TRUE, diff(data$x) <= 0)
f <- cumsum(abs(c(0, diff(d))))
tapply(data$y, f, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
unname(tapply(data$y, f, sum, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Which gives me this

```
[1] 420 180 390 120 330  60  30
```

But the problem is that I want it to count when increases until the maximum value such as ….,90,100,100, It stops at the first value 100 while I want it to continue at all values until reaches a lower one.

The output that I want is to appear this:

```
[1] 420 330 270 180 270 60 30
```

Comment: Is `times(51)` supposed to be `times=51`?

Comment: No it replicates 30 51 times, it is the same thing.

Comment: `Error in times(51) : could not find function "times"`. Are you using non-base R packages, or am I really confused about why your sample code does not work?

Comment: For clarity, `rep(30, times=51)` replicates 30 (51 times).

Comment: for me it works perfectly fine but it needs to library "chron" package. But both works.

Comment: Okay, I understand. That's a mis-use of the function, since it's intended to return objects that inherit from times. There is no reason for that to be a time-like thing, just a count-like thing.

Comment: I run the exact same code but instead it prints me this  [1] 30 390 330 240 180 270  60  30  For some reason the first is splitted

Comment: that's odd, same for me now ... stby

Comment: Now it gives me the right output thanks a lot!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Your data.

```r
x<-c(52,52,51,51,51,51,50,50,50,49,49,49,49,48,48,50,60,70,80,90,100,100,100,100,100,100,99,98,98,95,94,80,70,60,70,80,90,100,100,100,90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20,10,70,90,10)
y<-c(rep(c(30),times=51))
y<-c(NA,y)
data <- data.frame(x, y)
```

```r
d <- c(0, diff(data$x))
d[d==0] <- NA
d <- zoo::na.locf(zoo::na.locf(d, na.rm = FALSE), na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = TRUE)
f <- cumsum(abs(c(0, diff(d <= 0))))
tapply(data$y, f, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
#   0   1   2   3   4   5   6 
# 420 330 240 180 270  60  30
```